# Get IShellItem for Quick Access?

Tags: winapi

This failes with 0x80070057:

```cpp
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psi))
```

While this works for "My Computer":

```cpp
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psi))
```

Am I using the wrong GUID for Quick Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this GUID (`CLSID_HomeFolder`) is not officially documented.

You must use this type of parsing name instead for it to work (`shell:` is a url scheme):

```
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(L"shell:::{679F85CB-0220-4080-B29B-5540CC05AAB6}", NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psi));
```